# My Scrollable textview does not generate blue light

Tags: android, scroll, textview

My Scrollable textview does not generate blue light (any light at all) when reaches the top or bottom of a scrollview. And when it scrolls it does not scroll smoothly like other apps. The app is only has a single textview, but the scroll is not smooth. I really need the blue light to show, please help. Here is my xml and the code I used to make the TextView scrollable.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Scrolable"
    android:id="@+id/ScrolabletextView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:maxLines = "500"
    android:scrollbars = "vertical"
    android:overScrollMode="always"
    />
```

and I added this in the java file

```
    TextView textt;
    textt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ScrolabletextView);
    textt.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior that you are talking about comes with a `ScrollView`. You can simply wrap your text in a `ScrollView` to get it.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Scrolable"
        android:id="@+id/ScrolabletextView"
        android:maxLines = "500"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you!! :)  Problem fixed!